# TripleStore - no such Module

Tags: python, triplestore, rdflib

I have installed rdflib in python, it is in version 3.2
when i do this:

> > > import rdflib 
> > >       print rdflib.__ version__
> > >       3.2.0
> > >       from rdflib.TripleStore import TripleStore
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named TripleStore

Somebody help me with this please. :)

Comment: Should it exist? I mean, is TripleStore.TripleStore in dir(rdflib)? Otherwise, maybe you were meaning to import TripleStore from rdflib? (not familiar with the specific library, so I'm just guessing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TripleStore` was removed in rdflib 3.x and even in 2.4 it was deprecated in favor of `Graph`.

Use `Graph` in combination with [`Store`](http://www.rdflib.net/store/) to manage/persist your triples.

`TripleStore` was a subclass of `Graph` so it should be almost a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for pointing that out. I banged my head on the code for hours before realizing this. I had actually found Graph, but was thinking if TripleStore was any better. Subclass? meh!